# How can I fix this gpg error with Backup (deja-dup, duplicity)?

Tags: backup, gpg, duplicity, dejadup

Every day when I have a scheduled backup running, I see this error:

```
Error processing remote manifest (duplicity-inc.20190724T191929Z.to.20190726T191408Z.manifest.gpg): GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg: AES encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: essentially that says wrong passphrase provided. are you sure the passphrase you gave is correct? did you maybe change your gpg version inbetween?

..ede/duply.net

Comment: It's possible I typed my passphrase wrong. But how can I give another one?

Comment: seems to be not trivial. read here https://askubuntu.com/questions/109095/how-can-i-change-the-password-of-deja-dup-backup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remembered. most likely a gpg upgrade issue, see
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057627/duplicity-fails-with-bad-session-key-error

quoting from linked workaround in the above ticket

"
The problem is, like the linked post stated, that gpg 2.1 retires passphrase from pipe for key auth.
The gpg agents needs to be enabled and configured for the restore to work.

Add the following to ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf:

```
use-agent
pinentry-mode loopback
```

And to your ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf:

```
allow-loopback-pinentry
```

"

..ede/duply.net